# Disabling auto-fill in PHPStorm's find command

Tags: macos, phpstorm

When text is selected in the editor, hitting Cmd+F automatically fills the "find" box with the selected text, and places the cursor after the auto-pasted text.

I find it counter-productive as it breaks the regular flow of Cmd-C => Cmd-F => Cmd-V present in all other applications.
Is there a way to disable that behaviour?

Comment: But what is stopping you from keep doing your standard way? Why can't you just Cmd+V as you would usually do in another app? It works just fine.

Comment: @LazyOne Hitting Cmd-C + Cmd+F + Cmd+V results in the selected text being pasted twice ("texttext")

Comment: It works fine here (although I'm on Windows). Maybe there is a setting for preselecting the text (I believe so). Let me check...

Comment: Maybe it's you local OS settings? Or just Mac OS itself? I could not find anything in Settings and the only ticket I was able to find was asking opposite: to preselect the text. BTW -- what behaviour will you get when you invoke `Refactor | Rename` on something (e.g. file in Project View panel .. or a class name in Editor) -- will it preselect the text there?

Comment: It might just be specific to MacOS- but no other application has that behaviour that I know of.

`Refactor | Rename` prefills the text, and preselects it.

Comment: AFAIK it supposed to preselect the text. If you will not get any better answer in a day or two -- feel free to contact their [support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new) (and provide your `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in..)) -- devs may get you a better answer (why it preselects in certain fields and not in other on your OS).

Comment: I expect it to preselect the text, yes; I'll reach JetBrains if there is not obvious solution. Thanks for your help!